# \xef\xbb\xbf comes in utf8 files java

Tags: java, file, utf-8, mapping

I want to upload a UTF-8 file, while I create utf8 file in windows environment automatically adds
\xef\xbb\xbf this BOM in starting of the file.Problem is my file starting must be SOF because mapping tool will check this SOF.If I create normal ANSCII file it works ,When I save that file as UTF-8 it brings that unwanted BOM.Help me to create UTF-8 file without this BOM.

Comment: Are you using Notepad to create those files? The problem is just the tool used to create those files.

Comment: @BalusC yes Pal....... it is not showing anything if I use notepadd++ als0.but in mapper it gives that BOM.

Comment: As this question is tagged "java"... If you have the option of modifying the code that will be consuming the file, then you can use a [custom Reader implementation](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/tags/release-7.1/src/gate/util/BomStrippingInputStreamReader.java) to detect and ignore the BOM at read time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to create UTF-8 files without a BOM.

Comment: copy the content from here: http://pastebin.com/raw/4ptxdGex do a simple search replace to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using (free) CodeLobster PHP Edition to work with php, html, css and javascript. Upon saving a file, it will ask what type do you prefer - BOM or without it. Also, a file with BOM can be converted to BOM-less format.

You can also use any tool that would strip first three bytes of your file, although that would be pain in the butt in a long run...

[image: A BOM]
<sub>(source: [komprogram.pl](http://komprogram.pl/a_bom.jpg))</sub>

Oh, and with this app you can just delete a BOM if it didn't recognize encoding. It is not visible, but You just have to place a cursor on the start of the file and hit delete or backspace.